# Diameter of a set of points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was reading (in a real analysis book) about this topological (I think it's topological) concept "**diameter** of a set of points". And there's a side note there which says: the diameter of a triangle (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is equal to the length of its longest side.

This made me thinking... if we take two points $P,Q$ inside a **closed** triangle ABC with max side length $m$, how do we prove that $PQ \le m$. It seems to me it's not so easy, is it?

Also, is there an analogous statement for $\mathbb{R}^3$? Is it maybe about a tetrahedron (that the **diameter** of a tetrahedron is the length of its longest edge)? How does one prove that?

Sorry for the confusing tags, I am just not quite sure what tags to put here.

Comment: Thanks. But the question I am directed to obviously doesn't answer all the questions I asked. What about the analogue in the $R^3$ space?

Comment: The proof uses that $\Vert x-y \Vert^2$ is a convex function of both arguments, and therefore attains its maximum at extremal points on a convex set. The same argument works for a tetrahedron in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @MartinR OK, thanks, I will reread it, see if I can understand it in full. I was hoping for some more elementary proof but anyway. OK, thanks.